# How to check if Google/Facebook account has already been used to create account on Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on the signup/login of my app using Firebase Authentication.
I have custom buttons for Facebook Signup/Login and Google Signup/Login.

For example, the code for the Facebook Signup/Login button is

```
@objc private func performFacebookLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let fbLoginManager : LoginManager = LoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if result == nil {
                    print("no result!")
                    return
                }
                if AccessToken.current == nil {
                    print("no token")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    ThirdPartySignupViewController.push(fromVC: self, method: .facebook)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will take the user to another view controller to add additional information to their account **if they have not yet created an account** in the app using this Facebook account.

However, I can not find any way to determine whether or not the Facebook account has previously used for an account in the app, in which case I want to just log the user in and take them to the main screen. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried the `signIn(with:)` method, hoping that it would return an error if there is no account in the app with the credentials of this Facebook account, but this will not work because this will end up creating a new account if the Facebook account hasn't been used previously to create an account.

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
   //check if I get an error if the Facebook account has not been used             
}
```

(EDIT) The desired flow is 1.Sign in with Facebook/Google → 2.Enter additional info → 3.Create account on Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

When authenticating with Firebase - the `Auth` object returns [`isNewUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#public-abstract-boolean-isnewuser-) through [`additionalUserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser()). Therefore you can see the status of a new or existing user.

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        //authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser
        if let auth = authResult{
            if auth.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser {
                // User has not been authenticated before. Do what you need
            } else {
                // User has been authenticated before
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried this before posting, but as I said in the question, `.signIn(with:)` will create a new account before checking if the user is new or not. The desired flow is 1.Sign in with Facebook/Google → 2.Enter additional info → 3.Create account on Firebase Authentication.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a new account"? -- Given the `credential` is the same firebase won't create a new user within `Authentication`.

Comment: I mean create an account for my app on the database. So, I'm basically using Facebook and Google login as well as email/password so that it will be an easier to create an account on my app (no need to enter email, name, etc...), but the account for the app doesn't get created on my database until the user enters other necessary information on a view controller that appears after Facebook/Google login and presses "Create Account".

Comment: However, if I use `signIn(with:)`, a user will be added to Firebase Authentication regardless of whether or not the user ends up creating an account on the app, which I think is unnecessary. I think it would be best to add user to Firebase Authentication only after the user creates an account on the database, and I was wondering if there was a way to do this.

Comment: This method is currently neither supported nor good practise. What you need to do is either cache the users facebook token & proceed with the onboarding & create the account once all the data is provided. However, this doesn't answer your question. You can either log the user in, and if an error occurs ie; account cant be found, go onto onboarding. However, if a user just enters the wrong credentials then this is a bad UX. Ultimately, use your best judgement but there is no clear cut, supported way to solve your problem. Anything else let me know.